# Viewing items in a cart which is an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an OO shopping cart in javascript.  I've got it adding random products to a cart and I can click to get the basket.

How do I iterate over the basket items so that I can have a remove button beside each record?

I was thinking something along these lines:

```
    <body>
        <form action="#">
            <button onclick="cart().add();">Add Random Product</button>
            <button onclick="cart().getBasket();">View Cart</button>
        </form>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            for (var i=0; i < cart().getBasket().length; i++){
                console.log(cart().getBasket()[i]);
            }
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="shopping-cart.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                c$();
            });
        </script>
```

[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/757YGX4Rm6tnG1Mm80Hx?p=preview) is what I have so far.

I'm thinking of having a `renderBasket()` method which I can append to the dom.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `shoppingCart` is an array, you can use the [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) function from jQuery to iterate over it.

```
$("#shoppingCart").each(function( index, element) {
    console.log(index, element);
});
```